# Why is the set $[0\le f_1\le f_2]$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This question comes reading *Analysis III* of Amann and Escher. We set

$$[f\le\alpha]:=\{x\in X: f(x)\le\alpha\}$$

Then it is stated that if $f_1,f_2\in\mathcal L_0(X,\lambda_n,\overline{\Bbb R}^+)$, that is, each $f_k$ is Lebesgue measurable for some $X\subset\Bbb R^n$ Lebesgue measurable, then the set

$$[0\le f_1\le f_2]:=\{x\in X: 0\le f_1(x)\le f_2(x)\}\tag1$$

is $\lambda_n$-measurable. The book says that this is implied by the fact that

$$f\in\mathcal L_0(X,\lambda_m,\overline{\Bbb R})\iff \forall\alpha\in\overline{\Bbb R}:[f\le\alpha]\in\mathcal L(m)\tag2$$

where $\mathcal L(m)$ is the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra in $\Bbb R^m$. However I dont see how $(2)$ imply $(1)$. can someone show me the relation? Or, if this is not clear, can someone show me other way to see why $(1)$ is measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the intersection of the sets
$$ [f_1 \ge 0],\ [g \ge 0]$$
Where $g$ is the measurable function $g=f_2-f_1$.

Comment: oh, my god... what a dumb... yes, we can write $0\le f_1\le f_2$ as $0\le f_1\,\land\, f_1\le f_2$

Comment: @Masacroso yes, and yours is better actually since you allow the functions to take the value + infinity